# Where's this water coming from?

Tags: water, leak, foundation

The carpet outside the bathroom has two wet spots, as though water is seeping up from slab foundation. Cannot find any pipes leaking in bathroom, the spots are randomly positioned, about a foot into the bedroom. The carpet is soaking wet in these spots, but nowhere else. There has been no heavy rain lately. Home built in 1984, southern CA. Who do I call to look into this??

Comment: Wall-to-wall carpet, I presume? If you soak up the spots, do they return in the same place? Are they surrounded by dry carpet?

Comment: If the water supply lines are under the slab you may have leaks that are pushing the water up. One way to check is make sure all the faucets in the house are off and check your water meter if it is showing usage this may be the cause of wet spots. I have had this happen several times with copper supply lines. It is a real mess if not corrected as the leaks get bigger it erodes the soil under the slab.

Comment: I just remembered on the really bad house that I had a supply line leak under the slab I could hear the small rocks bouncing around. I used a wooden dowel pressed it hard into the carpet and put my ear on it, Some what like a stethoscope.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ed Beal. But, the culprit should be the bathroom. Lay paper towels (select-a-size) or a strip of toilet paper along the bath's adjoining wall to see if it gets wet anywhere.

I suspect it's coming from the toilet's seal at the floor & that seal needs replacement, they can leak a clear water stream & not be noticed. It could also be traveling under the finished floor, thus why it's depositing outside of the bathroom.